# Multi slider/percentage bars to sum 100% in one bar

Tags: angular, slider, progress-bar

I have to develop a multi-slider UI in angular like the one in the photo.

So far I found tools like [ngx-slider](https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/) or [infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/slider/slider) but they only use cases with 2 points to slide in the slider bar.

**Before I implement a custom solution**, I would like to ask if there is a tool out there to do the job.

[image: multi percentage bar]

Answer (score 1):

To anyone searching, [@vijayliebe/multi-range-slider tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vijayliebe/multi-range-slider) did the trick.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqcdhv) is the Stackblitz